# Assigning variable to an array (error)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm assigning a variable to an array that i declared in blade file. It returns an error of

```
ErrorException in 4c73f52d03e3e1331e7b4c0289cafb82dfc22253.php line 127:
Undefined offset: 0 (View:
/var/www/myteam/resources/views/servicedetails.blade.php)
```

Below is my code:

```
<?php $i = 0 ?>
@foreach($var as $v)
<?php $ary = array(); ?>
    <tr>
        <td name="attrname"><b>{{ $v->service_attribute_name }}</b><br><br></td>
        <td>: <a><input contenteditable="true" name="attrvalue" value="{{ $v->service_attribute_value}}"></a> <br></td>
        <?php $v->service_attribute_value = $ary[$i] ?>
        <?php $i++ ?>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I couldnt understand the error. Thank you!

Comment: Declare array `$ary` before foreach loop.
change this line `<?php $v->service_attribute_value = $ary[$i]; ?>`
with this
`<?php $ary[$i] = $v->service_attribute_value;  ?>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if `$ary = array()` is declared inside the `foreach` loop, any values you add to it will be overwritten by the next iteration of the loop, so the array will only provide you with the values of the final iteration of the loop.

Secondly, I think your issue is with this line:

```
<?php $v->service_attribute_value = $ary[$i] ?>
```

If you're trying to set the array value, you need to invert the order of this statement:

```
<?php $ary[$i] = $v->service_attribute_value ?>
```

Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

**Your code should be like this:**

```
<?php 
     $i = 0;
     $ary = array();
?>
@foreach($var as $v)
    <tr>
        <td name="attrname"><b>{{ $v->service_attribute_name }}</b><br><br></td>
        <td>: <a><input contenteditable="true" name="attrvalue" value="{{ $v->service_attribute_value}}"></a> <br></td>
        <?php 
             $ary[$i] = $v->service_attribute_value;
             $i++; 
        ?>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```